# Sending email with GWT: getting AccessControlException

Tags: java, email, gwt, access-denied

I have this issue that I cant seem to solve easily.

I want to send an email from within a GWT webApp. I did everything correctly in terms of putting the code in the server side and invoking it with an Async interface as its expected. So all is ok, except that when I execute the send email function, I get an error of type mailexception with and inner exception of type AccessControlException `"access denied (java.net.SocketPermission <my smtp server> resolve)"`.

Now I tested the function in a regular Java console app and it worked perfectly. So I guess I need to add some code to grant access somehow. Anyone can assist me in this?

Here is the code of the send email:

```
    public void SendMail(String name, String email, String message) throws EmailException{
    Email email1 = new SimpleEmail();
    email1.setHostName("mysmtpserver");
    email1.setSmtpPort(25);
    email1.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myemail", "mypwd"));
    email1.setTLS(false);
    email1.setFrom(email);
    email1.setSubject("Feedback from your website");
    email1.setMsg(escapeHtml(message));
    email1.addTo("targetemail");
    email1.send();
}
```

and that's the code of the class calling it:

```
public class SiteDataServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements SiteDataService {
@Override
public boolean SendEmail(String name, String email, String message) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        new Common().SendMail(name, email, message);
        return true;
    } catch (EmailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

PS: I thought at first that I need to include the mail.jar archive, but it is included in the gwt toolkit already, so its not the cause of the problem. And I am using Jetty with Eclipse.

Comment: To debug this create a simple project with just your mail piece and a main, then make sure you run it from the same machine as the GWT ser ver will be. That will give you the confidence that the mail code is running as expected.

Comment: Have you included activation.jar in the lib of your web app?

Comment: on second thought... it looks like some issue with your servers JRE check if they refer to the same version. Another place i would check is your smtp server settings.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I tried all of that with no positive results.

Comment: Have you tried a standalone java app with a simpl main? I suspect it has to do with some firewall settings

Comment: @Romain yep i tried, as written in my question. But its ok it works now, my guess its just the firewall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this may sound weird, but I deployed the code on a dev server  (linux) and it worked like a charm.

On my machine a windows one, it is still not working, and still getting the same error. But since it works on the dev machine, I am happy.

However this still doesnt explain the reason....